# R Error with axis break code (plotrix gap.plot)

Tags: r, plot, plotrix

When I try to break axis of a plot I always get an error. 
I use plotrix pkg.

My code so far:

```
xlim <- c(0,1)
ylim <- c(0,1)
gap.plot(evcent(USAN_g_num)$vector, betweenness(USAN_g_num, normalized=T), gap=c(0.4,0.6),gap.axis="y", xtics=c(0,0.3,0.7,1) ,xlim='xlim', ylim='ylim')
```

I get this error:

```
Error in rangexy[2] - rangexy[1] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Actually I think that I don't really need xlim and ylim. However I get an error that says me that xlim is missing if I don't use it.

Why I need a gap in Y-axis: My data ranges from 0 to 1 on both, x and y axis. On y axis I got an outlier. Therefore I have no datapoint between 0.4 and 0.6 on Y axis. Therefore I would like to cut this section out. 
What did I do wrong with my code?
Thank for any help & sorry for this - maybe - beginner question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your code is not reproducible because you do not provide `USAN_g_num`.

But try:

```
xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim
```

in your call to `gap.plot` instead of `xlim='xlim'` and `ylim='ylim'`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you are defining `xlim` and `ylim` outside of the call to `gap.plot`?

Otherwise, your error is due to passing a character string `'xlim'` to the argument rather than a numerical range. Try the following, which will have the added benefit of shortening your code and not storing `xlim` and `ylim` as global variables:

`gap.plot(evcent(USAN_g_num)$vector, betweenness(USAN_g_num, normalized=T), gap=c(0.4,0.6),gap.axis="y", xtics=c(0,0.3,0.7,1) ,xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1)`